# How to bind multiple options/select in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

I'll try my best to explain my scenario. I have a search filter which works when used in the following format in Angular 4:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="city_filter" (change)="applyFilter('city',$event.target.value)">
  <option value="Ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</option>
  <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
  <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
  <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
  <option value="Dilli">Dilli</option>
</select>
```

It stops working when I try the method:

```
   <select [(ngModel)]="city_filter" (change)="applyFilter('city',$event.target.value)">
      <option value="Ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</option>
      <option value="Bangalore/Bengaluru">Bangalore/Bengaluru</option>
      <option value="Delhi/Dilli">Delhi/Dilli</option>
    </select>
```

How do I make this work so that the filter works for both **Bangalore/Bengaluru**?

In the `applyFilter`, this is the function:

```
applyFilter (key: string, value) {
    this.filter.set(key, value);
    if (value === 'null') {
      this.filter.delete(key);
    }
    let p = new HttpParams();
    this.filter.forEach((v, k) => {
      p = p.append(k, v);
    });
    this.loading = true;
    this.jobService.searchJob(p).subscribe(res => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.valueStack = res;
      this.jobs = res.jobs || [];
    }, err => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.jobs = [];
    });
  }
```

Comment: you are missing a quotation at the end of your `ngModel`. I assume this was just an accident though because neither of these code scenarios would work for you then.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: Can you post what your'e doing in your `applyFilter` function? I don't see anything wrong with this html.

Comment: Updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: The set and delete operations do not like the fact that you have this character in the value you are passing in `/`. The person below mentions this. Try what they're saying, I won't bother adding another answer that says the same.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
 <option value="Bangalore/Bengaluru">Bangalore/Bengaluru</option>
```

Try this

```
 <option [ngValue]="'Bangalore' || 'Bengaluru'">Bangalore/Bengaluru</option>
```